# Derby DB - File size leak

Tags: java, database, memory-leaks, derby

Every now and then one of our remotely deployed java apps with a local derby db locks up due to waiting for a transaction to complete on a table. Every 24 hours the app syncs this derby db with our juggernaught oracle server, which means that after delivering its contents off, it clears all of its tables and then completely repopulates.

I opened the hood up and found that the .dat file for one of the tables has blown itself out to 100Mb. Im not sure exactly how long it takes to get to this point because the users generally arent around when the thing syncs. The gradual slowdown wasnt reported until it appeared to have completely stopped. Im also currently not sure logically how, since although autocommit is off, the code seems pretty tight.

After some googling I *think* what may have happened is an old transaction was somehow forgotten and neither commited nor rolled back - Future syncs which clear the table and repopulate essentially grow the file by it's original size every sync, since its tracking its entire history back to that old point.

Is there some way to confirm this and/or am I thinking completely down the wrong track? Is it possible to list old or long running transactions? If any are found, how can I clear them and will clearing them reclaim the disk space?